# Execute Insert command and return inserted Id in SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I am inserting some values into SQL Server table using C#. Actually I want to insert values and return the 'ID' of last inserted record. I use the following code:

```
string name = txt_name.Text.Trim();
string gender = Gender.Text.Trim();
string citizen = Citizen.Text.Trim();
int IdNo = Convert.ToInt32(idnumber.Text);

BUSSINESSACCESS.SENDMESSAGES send = new BUSSINESSACCESS.SENDMESSAGES();
DataSet dt = send.insertvoucher(name, gender, citizen, IdNo);
```

Business layer

```
public DataSet insertvoucher(string name, string gender, string citizen, int IdNo)
{
    SqlParameter[] par = {
                             new SqlParameter("@Name", name),    
                             new SqlParameter("@Citizen", citizen),
                             new SqlParameter("@Emiratesidno", IdNo),
                             new SqlParameter("@gender", gender),
                         };

    var rowCount = SHJCSQLHELPER.ExecuteScalar(CONNECTIONSTRING, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[INSERTVOUCHER]", par);

    return rowCount;
    // return SHJCSQLHELPER.ExecuteDataset(CONNECTIONSTRING, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[INSERTVOUCHER]", par);
    //string mn = "";
}
```

Stored procedure

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
Insert into Usertable(Name, Citizen, Emiratesidno, gender) 
values (@Name, @Citizen, @Emiratesidno, @gender)

SELECT scope_identity() AS int
```

I am getting the value in the variable rowcount but I cannot return the variable rowcount because it is saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'system.data.dataset'

Comment: `InsertVoucher` is supposed to return a `DataSet`.

Comment: Type of return value of method `insertvoucher` is `DataSet` but you returning `object`. I think you need change return type to `int` and then cast `rowCount` to integer `return (int)rowCount;`

Comment: And name of `rowCount` is misleading, since you expecting `id`

Comment: ExecuteScalar does not return a DataSet, so you need to change your method signature DataSet insertvoucher to int insertvoucher. Also cast rowCount to (int)rowCount during the return

Comment: dear fabio i tried that one its saying now 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'system.data.dataset'
'

Comment: Change `DataSet dt = send.insertvoucher(name, gender, citizen, IdNo);` to `var newId = send.insertvoucher(name, gender, citizen, IdNo);`

Comment: {"Specified cast is not valid."} the error is coming like that

Comment: @user3377634, which line throws this error?

Comment: not it is working thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are not casting, you are aliasing column name to int,

   Use: `SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)`
2. `rowCount` is boxed integer. change return statement and return type. Example:

> return (int)rowCount;

This would be your required ID.

Ref: [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Prepend your Execute command with `(Int32)`

```
var rowCount =  (Int32)SHJCSQLHELPER.ExecuteScalar(CONNECTIONSTRING, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "[INSERTVOUCHER]", par);
```

`scope_identity()` returns an `INT` by default, no need to cast it.

You could also setup the stored procedure to use an OUT parameter and assign the `Scope_Identity()` to that and adjust your C# to utilize this

**Correction**
`scope_identity()` returns a `decimal` and not an `int`. If your `identity` column is an `int` the conversion is automatic and no casting is needed.

I am a little rusty on this as I am utilizing `output` parameters in the majority of my Stored Procedures and not returning a `select` statement

Comment: Actually Scope_Identity() returns numeric(38,0)

Comment: do i have to change the dataset to int

Comment: Yes on changing the type of the return, and I have corrected to reflect correct numeric type